# Downloading historical data of "Financial Account Data"

Tags: data

I would like to know how to download historical data from

[www.federalreserve.gov/apps/fof/FOFTables.aspx](https://www.federalreserve.gov/apps/fof/FOFTables.aspx)

Please advise.

Comment: what data specifically do you need?

Comment: Data Download Program: https://www.federalreserve.gov/datadownload/. Have a read and give an example if you have issues.

Comment: Is this it? If so I'll add it to the answer. https://www.federalreserve.gov/datadownload/Download.aspx?rel=Z1&series=6ef83e2f7498e255430af88f48acd91c&lastobs=5&from=&to=&filetype=csv&label=include&layout=seriesrow&type=package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page explains how to choose what type of data to download: 
https://www.federalreserve.gov/datadownload/help/default.htm#chooseData

I navigated [here](https://www.federalreserve.gov/datadownload/Download.aspx?rel=Z1&series=6ef83e2f7498e255430af88f48acd91c&lastobs=5&from=&to=&filetype=csv&label=include&layout=seriesrow&type=package), which I think is what you want.